# How to translate this list comprehension statement?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to understand the following code:

```
for page in iterate_PR:
    p2 = [link for link in corpus if page in corpus[link]]
```

My thinking is if written in long form the code should per below:

```
for page in iterate_PR:
    for link in corpus:
        if page in corpus[link]:
            p1.append(link)
```

However when I print p1 and p2 I'm not getting the same results. Where am I wrong?

Comment: "if written in long form"—first of all, list comprehensions and loops are fundamentally different things. One isn't a "long form" or "short form" of the other.

Comment: the first code will replace p2 at every iteration

Comment: @Chris Well, I'm trying to learn python. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Please read https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for page in iterate_PR:
    p2 = []
    for link in corpus:
        if page in corpus[link]:
            p2.append(link)
```

As mentioned by [python_learner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12502959/python-learner) in his answer, p2 is reset for every page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the large version:

```
p2 = []
for page in iterate_PR:
    for link in corpus:
        if page in corpus[link]:
            p2.append(link)
```

Code is appending to `p1` not `p2`!

Comment: So I was just trying to compare the two results. p1 and p2 should have the same output.

Answer (score 0):

It can be represented as:

```
for page in iterate_PR:
    p2 = []
    for link in corpus:
        if page in corpus[link]:
            p2.append(link)
```

Comment: Got it, I had defined my p2 list outside of the loop!